# Consortium vs. Permissioned Blockchains

Tags: blockchain, permissioned-chain

I hear these two terms interchangeably **Consortium Blockchain** and **Permissioned Blockchain**. Are they the same?
If not, can you please show the difference between them.

P.S. Since there exists no general (StackExchange) Blockchain community, I am asking my question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're not quiet the same thing but they are often related since consortiums prefer to ensure that their perimeter / border is not breached.

Consortium typically refers to a group of corps or entities working in the same field. A Consortium Blockchain is then a generalized data-sharing platform for them.

A Permissioned Blockchain typically means a client / software that is capable of ensuring that the nodes / clients connecting to it are permissioned (allowed) prior to establishing and sharing connectivity.

Comment: Thanks @fixanoid. Do you mean that a Consortium BC is related to interoperability across heterogeneous chains?

Comment: @fixanoid so who allow join permission in case of permissioned blockchain ?

Comment: @cryptoKTM -- generally, there is an agreement between a group parties when chain is created. These are then permissioned appropriately via genesis block. This block is a config like json (since Quorum is a fork of geth) and it contains initial permission config. If everyone agrees that its correct outside of chain, each participant created their node, shares their connectivity details and the chain is initiated.